# Logstash pipeline is failing when adding filter block in it

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elk

I am creating logstash pipeline where I am giving log file as an input and reading those logs on elasticsearch. I want to add `geoip` filter in my logstash pipeline configuration but when I am adding it's failing and shutting down.

[image]

Here is an errors:

```
[2022-03-17T12:41:05,243][WARN ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] 
Elasticsearch Output configured with `ecs_compatibility => v8`, which 
resolved to an UNRELEASED preview of version 8.0.0 of the Elastic Common 
Schema. Once ECS v8 and an updated release of this plugin are publicly 
available, you will need to update this plugin to resolve this warning.
[2022-03-17T12:41:05,293][ERROR][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] 
Pipeline error {:pipeline_id=>"main", :exception=># 
<LogStash::ConfigurationError: GeoIP Filter in ECS-Compatiblity mode 
requires a `target` when `source` is not an `ip` sub-field, eg. [client] 
[ip]>, :backtrace=>["D:/logstash- 
8.1.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-filter-geoip-7.2.11- 
java/lib/logstash/filters/geoip.rb:143:in `auto_target_from_source!'", 
"D:/logstash-8.1.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-filter-geoip- 
7.2.11-java/lib/logstash/filters/geoip.rb:133:in `setup_target_field'", 
"D:/logstash-8.1.0/vendor/bundle/jruby/2.5.0/gems/logstash-filter-geoip- 
7.2.11-java/lib/logstash/filters/geoip.rb:108:in `register'", 
"org/logstash/config/ir/compiler/AbstractFilterDelegatorExt.java:75:in 
`register'", "D:/logstash-8.1.0/logstash- 
core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:232:in `block in register_plugins'", 
"org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1821:in `each'", "D:/logstash-8.1.0/logstash- 
core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:231:in `register_plugins'", 
"D:/logstash-8.1.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:590:in 
`maybe_setup_out_plugins'", "D:/logstash-8.1.0/logstash- 
core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:244:in `start_workers'", 
"D:/logstash- 
8.1.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:189:in `run'", 
"D:/logstash-8.1.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:141:in `block in start'"], "pipeline.sources"=>["D:/logstash-8.1.0/my-logstash.conf"], :thread=>"#<Thread:0x6ea94258 run>"}
[2022-03-17T12:41:05,314][INFO ][logstash.javapipeline    ][main] Pipeline terminated {"pipeline.id"=>"main"}
[2022-03-17T12:41:05,357][INFO ][logstash.outputs.elasticsearch][main] Using a default mapping template {:es_version=>8, :ecs_compatibility=>:v8}
[2022-03-17T12:41:05,390][ERROR][logstash.agent           ] Failed to execute action {:id=>:main, :action_type=>LogStash::ConvergeResult::FailedAction, :message=>"Could not execute action: PipelineAction::Create<main>, action_result: false", :backtrace=>nil}
[2022-03-17T12:41:05,499][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.os] Stopping
[2022-03-17T12:41:05,523][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.jvm] Stopping
[2022-03-17T12:41:05,525][DEBUG][logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.persistentqueue] Stopping
[2022-03-17T12:41:05,532][DEBUG] 
[logstash.instrument.periodicpoller.deadletterqueue] Stopping
[2022-03-17T12:41:05,556][DEBUG][logstash.agent           ] Shutting 
down all pipelines {:pipelines_count=>0}
```

When I am using below configuration without filter, then it's working fine:

```
input {
 file {
  path => "D:/nest/es-logging-example/log/info/*.log"
  start_position => beginning
  sincedb_path => "NULL"
 }
}

output {
 elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "myapplogs"
 }
 stdout{}
}
```

But on adding filter in configuration file then it's failing and shutting down:

```
input { 
 file {
  path => "D:/nest/es-logging-example/log/info/*.log"
  start_position => beginning
  sincedb_path => "NULL"
  }
}
filter {
 geoip {
    source => "clientip"
 }
}
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => "localhost:9200"
    index => "myapplogs"
  }
  stdout{}
}
```

What I am doing wrong in 2nd configuration?

Comment: Can you run logstash with `--debug` and share the output, please?

Comment: I have updated my error in post after running it in debugging mode.

Comment: I think error is related with `geoip` filter.

Comment: The error is pretty clear: `GeoIP Filter in ECS-Compatiblity mode 
requires a `target` when `source` is not an `ip` sub-field. You're simply missing an explicit `target` field

Comment: Means what should I need to do  can u please help me out

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What the error states is this

> GeoIP Filter in ECS-Compatiblity mode requires a `target` when `source` is not an `ip` sub-field. You're simply missing an explicit `target` field

So your filter should look like this:

```
filter {
 geoip {
    source => "clientip"
    target => "clientgeo"
 }
}
```

Comment: Pipeline is working fine now but in elastoc search its showing `field -tags`  and `value - _geoip_lookup_failure`.

Comment: I have added the snapshot of kibana u can see the filed and values